# Object declaration and initialization in Rust

Tags: object, rust, initialization

```
pub struct Person
{
    name: String,
    age: u32,
}

impl Person {
    pub fn new(name: String, age: u32) -> Person {
        Person { name, age }
    }
    pub fn show(self)
    {
        println!("Name: {}, Age: {}", self.name, self.age);
    }
}

fn main()
{
    let person = Person { name: "Alice".to_string(), age: 33 }; // (1)<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    let person2 = Person::new("Bob".to_string(), 99 );// (2)<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

What is the difference between (1) and (2) in the above source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Direct struct instantiation syntax. Because the fields `name` and `age` are not marked `pub`, this can only be used within the module it's defined.
2. Function call construction. Since the function is `pub`, it can be used from any module that can access `Person`.

Other than the visibility difference, both will act identically.

Comment: Does #1 have any parallel in C++, Java, or C#?

Comment: Not really. All of those languages allow for partial construction - Rust does not.